# Project interpreter with Pycharm (with Anaconda plugin). How can I resolve this error telling me that pycharm "Failed to Create Interpreter"?

Tags: python, pycharm, anaconda, interpreter, miniconda

I used to use Pycharm, then switched to Miniconda and used Spyder for a time, now I'm back to using Pycharm (this time the version with an Anaconda plugin). I've been able to set up a project and run it successfully, but I tried to create a new project and can't figure out how to configure a new interpreter for the new project. I've been able to get my new project to run by using the Project Interpreter from my old project, but I would like to create a new one as these are separate projects.

I would like to use a conda environment for the project interpreter.

Here is the error I am receiving: [Error Message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVLVM.png)

I've pasted the error message here for you:

```
Collecting package metadata: ...working... failed

UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid.

channel name: pypi
channel url: https://pypi.python.org/pypi
error code: 404

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use conda config --show channels to view your configurations current state,
and use conda config --show-sources to view config file locations.
```

I know I've created a new environment for my new projects but I'm still a beginner and I'm not sure if I'm doing it correctly. I'm also not very familiar with any of the general rules of thumb for configuring projects and environments using Pycharm (obviously, or I wouldn't be having this problem). I'd love to get any extra information you can give, as I would like to learn, but bear in mind that I'm not familiar with a lot of of the terminology so if you can explain to me like I'm a kid I wouldn't mind.

Comment: Is `https://pypi.python.org/pypi` available from your browser?

Comment: Yes, it is. I should add that this error pops up as soon as I try to add the new project interpreter for this project ("File" --> "Settings" --> "Project --> "Project Interpreter" -->gear drop down--> "Add...").

Comment: As mentioned before, I'm currently using the Project Interpreter set up for my last project, but I would rather use a new one. It may also be notable that if I click the "+" button on the project interpreter menu it says "nothing to show", and if I click on the manage repositories from there is says the same thing. If I add a repository (like https://pypi.python.org/pypi), it shows up (and for moment a pop-up dialogue window says it is creating a conda channel, then disappears), but upon leaving the window and opening it again, it is empty again.

Comment: Conda does not use repositories, it uses channels https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/concepts/channels.html so pypi should not be added as a repository. Anyway, could you please try to run failed command (see your screenshot) in Anaconda Prompt?

Comment: Ok, yes that makes sense about the repositories. I've tried to create the environment in Anaconda Navigator rather than PyCharm, and I get the same error: "UnavailableInvalidChannel: The channel is not accessible or is invalid.
channel name: pypi
channel url: https://pypi.python.org/pypi
error code: 404

You will need to adjust your conda configuration to proceed.
Use `conda config --show channels` to view your configuration's current state,
and use `conda config --show-sources` to view config file locations."

Comment: When I use conda config --show channels to view the state, sure enough, it shows a channel for https://pypi.python.org/pypi.  I'm not sure why it is pulling up the error if the channel is there.

Comment: Additionally, I found that if I change to the python.exe file in my Miniconda folder, rather than the conda.exe file in the Scripts folder of the Miniconda folder (where it was pulling from before), I get the following error: "C:\Users\<username>\Miniconda3\python.exe: can't open file 'create': [Errno 2] No such file or directory".

Comment: Let's try to remove this channel and check if everything is fine? See https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/commands/remove.html#Channel%20Customization